# Can I claim a credit / deduction on my "personal income tax" for the "city corporate income tax" that my LLC company located in NYC had to pay?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, limited-liability-company

I live in Chicago, which does not have city income tax. My company is a LLC incorporated in NYC, which has city income tax. So my understanding is that my company needs to pay "**city** income tax" over its revenue because it is in NYC.

It is also my understanding that the net profits of my company (revenue - expenses - city taxes, etc.) will go to me and then I'll have to pay personal income taxes (federal and state) over that received income.

My question is: Am I entitled to any credit / deduction / anything on my personal income taxes (federal and/or state)  because of the fact that I live in Chicago (no city taxes here) and my company is in NYC paying city taxes? Am I doing something wrong, something less optimal for tax purposes, assuming I'm not able to move my company to Chicago in the short run?